# How to get the last file created on Linux using pscp PuTTY?

Tags: linux, putty

I'm accesing an Ubuntu system using pcsp from PuTTY on a Windows PC. 
I need to retrive the last file created on a folder.

For now i only have a script that retrieves all the files on a folder:

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY;%PATH%
pscp
pscp finaltest@192.168.1.26:unit_logs/* C:\Users\Zasil-Ha\Documents
```

How so I do to get the last file created on unit_logs folder???

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I doubt you can.  You might have to look for an alternative, like having a script on the linux box update a symlink to point at the latest file.  Then you can simply use the symlink to copy the latest file.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to make a script the other way around. Push the latest file from Linux to Windows.
To do this:

```
scp `ls -c|head -n1` user@windows_machine:<path>
```

Comment: and yes, you may have to install ssh-server on your Windows computer :)